# roscore, errors out?

Tags: ros, embedded, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installation of Diamondback SVN on a 10.10 Ubuntu (BeagleBoard) system.

```
>$ roscore
>"logging info"
>Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
>Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
>Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
>;roscore
>started roslaunch servo http://Evolve:54621
>ros_comm version 1.4.5
>
>SUMMARY
>
>PARAMETERS
>* /rosversion
>* /rosdistro
>
>NODES
>
>auto-starting new master 
>process[master]: started with pid [1526]
>ROS_MASTER_URI=http://Evolve:11311/
>;roscore http://Evolve:11311/
>setting /run_id to 1df08...
>
>[rosout-1] killing on exit
>[master] killing on exit
```

Its just exiting on itself, need fix ASAP.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9496/roscore,-errors-out?/) by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your last logfile (http://pastebin.com/RCKePPas):

```
[roslaunch][ERROR] 1969-12-31 17:01:13,760: OSError(8, Exec format error)
[roslaunch][ERROR] 1969-12-31 17:01:13,763: Unable to launch [rosout-1].
```

... seems to be the relevant error. I don't know anything about the BeagleBoard but since it's not x86 (correct?) I'm guessing you have some cross-compilation issues.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-20**:
Almost certainly the case.  Beagleboard is an ARM board. There has been some work started over here: http://dave.limoilux.org/trac/wiki/ROS/CrossCompile/arm but it's far from complete.  You can probably also work off the gumROS guide: http://www.ros.org/wiki/gumros as a starter.